# Orbeon Forms: <FR:IF CONDITION doe not trigger

Tags: orbeon

Some basic help please.. I have written the following action which triggers OK when a radio button option is selected:

However, the two "***fr:if condition...***" statements below do not trigger and update MyNumber field.

Any suggestions welcome.

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. `fr:control-string-value()` takes the control as its first parameter, but you're passing `'PONRAQ1/string()'`. Instead you just want to be calling `fr:control-string-value('PONRAQ1')`. See [doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-control-string-value).
2. If you have a plain Yes/No Answer control, its value is a boolean, and so either `true` or `false` (not `yes` and `no`, despite the name). So you'll want to say `fr:control-string-value('PONRAQ1') = 'true'`.

Hint: you can debug this type of code using `<fr:alert>` ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/actions-syntax#alert-for-debugging)).

Comment: I had already tried fr:control-string-value('POWRAQ1'), but that didn't work either.

Also, it is not a Yes/No control, it is a multi-radio-button with a yes/no value (lower case). I tried a true/false value just in case, but that didnt work (as expected).

I also added a line after each "if" statement to set a value, and those lines triggered and update the control value as expected.

See example form: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/7cf4e4aac90aa717adaeeaa21009bd6a7deb55be

Regards 

PeteA